# Why won't my fishes turn around?

Tags: java, animation, graphics

I'm having trouble moving my fishes to another place and turn around when they reach the right or left edge. The window is 600 x 400. In method `void swim();`, whatever I change the fish just goes to the same spot (the fish past the right edge of the window). How can I move the fish and when it reaches the right edge or left and turn around and move to the left edge of the window?

Note: I am using [`GWindow`](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse14x/info/javadocs/graphics/uwcse/graphics/GWindow.html), which is a class provided by my school.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;    
import uwcse.graphics.*;

/**
 * A fish in a graphics window
 */

public class Fish {
    public static final int LEFT_MOVING = 0;
    public static final int RIGHT_MOVING = 0;

    // The graphics window the fish belongs to
    private GWindow window;

    // The location of the fish
    private int x;

    private int y;

    // Scale of the drawing of the fish
    private double scale;

    private Color color;

    private int direction;

    private Oval O1; Oval O2;
    private Triangle tail1; Triangle tail2;
    private Line eye1; Line eye2;

    /**
     * Draws a Fish in a graphics window
     * 
     * @param x
     *            the x coordinate of the location of the fish
     * @param y
     *            the y coordinate of the location of the fish
     * @param scale
     *            the scale of the drawing of the fish
     * @param window
     *            the graphics window the fish belongs to
     */

    public Fish(int x, int y, double scale,int direction, GWindow window) {
        // Initialize the instance fields
        this.x  = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.window = window;
        this.color = randomColor();
        this.direction = direction;

        // Draw the fish
        this.draw();
    }
    private Color randomColor(){
        Random random = new Random();
        int R = random.nextInt(256);
        int G = random.nextInt(256);
        int B = random.nextInt(256);
        return new Color(R,B,G);            
    }       

    /**
     * Draws this fish
     */
    private void draw() {

        int Fsize = (int)(this.scale*15);

        this.O1 = new Oval(
                this.x - Fsize /3,                                        
                this.y - Fsize /7 ,               
                Fsize + 4*Fsize/3,                                        
                Fsize  + Fsize/5,                                              
                this.color,true);       
        this.tail1 =new Triangle(
                this.x - Fsize,                                                              
                this.y,                                                         
                this.x - 2/Fsize,                                                        
                this.y + Fsize/2,                                                        
                this.x - Fsize,                                                      
                this.y + Fsize,this.color,true);
        this.eye1 = new Line(
                this.x + 15*Fsize/10,                                       
                this.y + 5*Fsize/10  ,                                      
                this.x + 15 *Fsize/10,                                      
                this.y + 5* Fsize /10,                                      
                Color.BLACK);   
        Oval O2 = new Oval(
                this.x - 37*Fsize/5,                      
                this.y+ 27*Fsize/5 ,                     
                Fsize + 2*Fsize/3,    
                Fsize  + Fsize/5,                   
                this.color,true);       
        Line eye2 = new Line(                
                this.x - 35*Fsize/5,                 
                this.y + 30*Fsize/5,                
                this.x - 35*Fsize/5,                 
                this.y + 30*Fsize/5, Color.BLACK);                      
        Triangle tail2 =new Triangle(
                this.x - Fsize*5 ,              
                this.y + 13*Fsize/2,                 
                this.x - 10*Fsize/2,                 
                this.y + 11*Fsize/2,                 
                this.x - Fsize*6,                
                this.y + Fsize*6,this.color,true);          
        this.window.add(O1);
        this.window.add(O2);
        this.window.add(tail2);
        this.window.add(tail1);
        this.window.add(eye1);
        this.window.add(eye2);
    }


    public void moveBy (int dx, int dy){
        x += dx;
        y += dy;        
    }

    public void swim(){
        if (RIGHT_MOVING >= 250 || this.direction == RIGHT_MOVING){
            this.O1.moveBy(3,0);
            this.tail1.moveBy(3,0);
            this.eye1.moveBy(3,0);
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for fish collision with boundaries, and if so, then change the animation settings to change the direction of movement. This will entail using an if block or two in the code where you move the fish. In pseudocode, it would look like:

```
if fish location is equal to or less than 0 
   change deltaX to a positive value
if fish location + fish width is equal to or greater than width of tank
   change deltaX to a negative value 

move fish by deltaX
```

I usually use the absolute values of the detlaX, i.e.,

```
deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX);
```

and

```
deltaX = -Math.abs(deltaX);
```

rather than simply swapping signs. The reason is that if you simply swap signs, you risk getting the fish stuck at the corner.